# Scripting.FileSystemObject wrong read a file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activexobject

I try to read a local file by javascript in IE 8 & 9.

My script:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fso.OpenTextFile(file_name, 1, true);
var file_content = file.ReadAll();
file.Close();
```

A file has been reading successfully. But one byte of all file is wrong. `file_content.charCodeAt(8)` return to me `1038`, but should be `161`. And some other bytes same as in file.

My data file is:

```
0000000000: 03 0C 0A 1A 01 00 00 00 │ A1 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00
0000000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000000020: 4F 42 4A 45 43 54 49 44 │ 00 00 00 4E 00 00 00 00
0000000030: 04 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000000040: 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 4E 00 00 00 00
0000000050: 0A 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000000060: 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 4E 00 00 00 00
0000000070: 0A 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000000080: 56 41 4C 55 45 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 4E 00 00 00 00
0000000090: 06 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000000A0: 0D 20 31 2E 30 30 31 34 │ 36 38 35 39 33 2E 30 30
00000000B0: 35 33 33 31 38 38 35 2E │ 30 30 31 30 30 2E 30 30
00000000C0: 1A                      │
```

P.S. I read this file by Mozilla Firefox, Chrome and Chromium by next code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

if (jQuery.browser.mozilla) {
  slice = file.mozSlice(0, file.size);
}
else {
  slice = file.slice(0, file.size);
}

reader.onload = function(e) {
  if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
    file_content = e.target.result;
  }
};
```

And in this browsers `file_content.charCodeAt(8)` return to me `161`.

Can you advise to me in this case? May be I do something wrong.

Comment: It seems that Internet Explorer processes your file as unicode and does surrogate pair replacement when converting it to a string, while the other browsers do not. If you want it to behave as Chrome and Mozilla, try opening it as a binary file, not a text file. (Also, it's probably wrong to work with binary data using `charCodeAt()`.)

Comment: In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) written: if format is omitted, the file is opened as ASCII. Otherwise, I didn't know how to open a file as binary.